# Should I use pitched memory in CUDA for read-only 2D arrays?

Tags: memory-management, cuda

I am porting some code from CPU to GPU, and in CPU side I have a dynamically allocated matrix (`double **`) which is to be ported to GPU. However, once initialized, matrix is never modified. Since I can't use pointers to pointers on GPU, should I represent this matrix as a flat array (`double *` accessed as `matrix[i * nCols + j]`) or use pitched memory for it? Will the use of pitched memory lead to performance improvement in this case?

Comment: `Since I can't use pointers to pointers on GPU` You can. `should I represent this matrix as a flat array [...] or use pitched memory for it? [...] Will the use of pitched memory lead to performance improvement in this case?` It depends on the size of your matrix rows and your access patterns. I'd say, use whatever is simpler for you at first to get a working GPU version of your code (probably flat arrays). If you have bank conflicts, consider the usage of pitched memory as a future improvement.

Comment: bank conflicts?  The usage of pitched memory, at least that allocated by `cudaMallocPitch` or similar, doesn't have anything to do with bank conflicts.  If you have bank conflicts, you may wish to focus on your access patterns to (and/or reorganization of your data patterns in) *shared* memory.  The question appears to have the usage of *global* memory in view.

Comment: Yes, that's completely wrong. No idea why I said bank conflicts.

Comment: Use of pitched memory may provide somewhat higher global access efficiency, since it aligns the start of each row (or column, depending on storage convention used) for the GPU's wide memory transfers. Whether that matters in this use case is impossible to say without knowing the access pattern and whether the code is memory bound. I would start with a simple flat array and consider use of pitched memory as something to be investigated during the fine-tuning stage of performance optimizations, informed by profiler data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only instance I can think of that using pitched memory could perform worse for a 2D array instead of linear memory is if you directly access the memory using:

```
int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
double myVal=_d_array[tid];
```

Otherwise, pitch will at the least align the first entry of each row. A read through:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/#coalesced-access-to-global-memory
will most definitely help your understanding. If your rows are small (~16 entries), or you're using a 2.x compute capability card you could see significant performance improvements when you access data row by row with pitch instead of linear layout.

Worst case without pitch for row by row with a 2.x capability card could be close to 50% bandwidth for an unaligned grab of 16 double values. This could also thrash your L1 cache pretty bad, as that will boot out an extra L1 cache line.

Due to non L1 caching in 3.x an unaligned grab of 16 doubles will result in 32B*5 grab into L2 instead of 32B*4 so the performance hit will likely be "small".

One thing to keep in mind is making block sizes multiples 32 is typically a good idea.